# Reset p:tabView into p:Dialog JSF Application

Tags: primefaces

I have a `p:dialog` around it consisting of a `p:tabView`, the button that triggers the Dialog has a Quality Action of a method to initialize the screen data, however open a Dialog, scroll in the tabs and refresh it again not Returns to a first tab, always selected with a last visit.

I'm using the:

```
< p:dialog header="Produto e Serviço" widgetVar="produtoServDialog" id="produtoServ-dialog" resizable="true" modal="true" closeOnEscape="true" height="90%" width="90%">

< p:tabView id="tabViewProdutos" dynamic="true" scrollable="true" prependId="false" cache="false" activeIndex="0">
```

Comment: What does 'refresh it again' mean?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you you can select the first tab in the `onShow` attribute of the dialog. The `select` method is zero-based. `activeIndex` is only used the first time the tabview is shown (and if you do as below, it will not have any effect).

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('dialogwv').show()" value="Show"/>   
    </h:form>

    <p:dialog widgetVar="dialogwv" onShow="PF('tabviewwv').select(0)">
        <h:form>
            <p:tabView widgetVar="tabviewwv">
                <p:tab title="aaa">aaa</p:tab>
                <p:tab title="bbb">bbb</p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```